# Android LocationListener stopped working

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an Android app (minSDK=8) and this app has a map with the current location of the user being painted on it. 
Yesterday, I was fixing some bugs with route making, and it was all good. Then, I dunno what I did, but the current location of the device stopped working. I tried to debug, and I noticed the OnLocationChanged callback is never called. Then, I reverted to an old version using Git, that I'm positive it was working, and it does not work. So I think there is a problem with my device. Then, to check it for sure, I opened the Maps app, and it worked perfectly. So... I don't know what to do. I double checked the Settings-> Location services tab, and all 3 options (GPS, Network and Google Location) are enabled.

Just to show part of my code:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Maps activity:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    if (currentPosition == null){
                        currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        gas_list = new ArrayList<Gasolineres>();
                        gas_marker_list = new ArrayList<Marker>();
                        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, obteEstacions, "MagentoBackground");
                        thread.start();

                    } else {
                        currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    }
                    if (currentPosition != null){
                        if (myPosition == null){                            
                            myPosition = mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).snippet("Lat: " + currentPosition.latitude + "\nLon: " + currentPosition.longitude).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current)));
                        } else {
                            myPosition.setPosition(currentPosition);
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);     
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

The thing is, I put a breakpoint into the onLocationChanged() and it's never called. I dont' t know what to do. If I have access to another device, I'll try with it.

Comment: I have the same problem now, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you gps is not working correctly... Try putting Log in your app, so you can watch across the DDMS logcat when is called that method, Try this in the method:

```
Log.d(TAG, "OnLocationChanged was called");
```

Too try installing apps like GPS Status, to see if your GPS is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart you phone. Sometimes it helps with strange GPS issues